# Will it be possible to access SNMP MIB (agent in Mobile) via EPS Bearer (4G transportation layer) from Manager?

Tags: snmp, eps, mib, 4g

It will be really helpful to know the mechanism for accessing the MIB database located in the mobile phone (snmp agent) from snmp manager (located in remote server) connected to internet. Could someone please clarify.
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: UDP is not reliable over the Internet, but SNMP should work if there is no firewall to block. What do you mean by "MIB database", there is no such thing in the specification.

Comment: Sorry, I meant MIB. I use it for storing status info.